# Updates matlab structure fields

Tags: matlab

Can you help me? 
My script is:

```
clear all
clc
load vertici.mat    
load posizioni.mat 
posizione1_row= posizioni(1,:);
DIS=[];
E1= posizione1_row(1:3);
E2= posizione1_row(4:6);
E3= posizione1_row(7:9);
E4= posizione1_row(10:12);
E5= posizione1_row(13:15);
E6= posizione1_row(16:18);
E7= posizione1_row(19:21);
E8= posizione1_row(22:24);
E9= posizione1_row(25:27);
E10= posizione1_row(28:30);

posizione1= [E1;E2;E3;E4;E5;E6;E7;E8;E9;E10];

for p=1:size (posizione1,1)
    for q=1:size(N,1)
        ind= sqrt((N(q,1)-posizione1(p,1))^2+(N(q,2)-posizione1(p,2))^2+(N(q,3)-posizione1(p,3))^2); 
        DIS=[DIS;ind];    
    end

    [MinDIS , IndexN ]= min(DIS); 
    CoorMin= N(IndexN,:) ;         

    distanze(p).elettrodo= posizione1(p,:);
    distanze(p).distmin= MinDIS;
    distanze(p).puntoSup= CoorMin;

end
```

I don't understand why the field "distmin" and the field "puntoSup" don't change during `for` iterations!! What is the error??

Thanks

Comment: how do you know that? what test do you run?

Comment: You need to clear `DIS` (or set it to `[]`) inside your `for p` loop, before you start your `for q` loop.